# difference between GMSK (Gaussian Minimum shift keying) and GFSK (Gaussain frequency shift keying)

Tags: digital-communications, modulation, digital, frequency-modulation, gmsk

I am unable to differentiate GMSK and GFSK. 
How do the modulation techniques differ in Tx?

How do their receiving techniques differ..?

Comment: http://www.edaboard.com/thread5788.html

Comment: With GMSK the frequency modulation index is 0.5.  With GFSK, the frequency modulation index is larger than 0.5 (the signaling tones are farther apart).

Comment: @AndyWalls you should add this as an answer below, short answers are ok!

Answer (score 3):

With GMSK, the frequency modulation index is 0.5. With GFSK, the frequency modulation index is larger than 0.5 (the signaling tones are farther apart).

The receiving techniques used for GMSK as an FSK work for GFSK.

Comment: Welcome to SE...is this Andy "Mr. Storage" Walls of IBM?

Comment: @Dan_Boschen : Nope.  I'm the Andy Walls that hangs around the GNURadio community and also the same one listed as the maintainer of the cx18 driver in the Linux kernel.

Comment: Great, then your Andy "Mr cx18" Walls, then- I always get the two confused! Nice to meet you.

Comment: It seems like the GNURadio code for GFSK (https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/blob/master/gr-digital/python/digital/gfsk.py) mod & GMSK mod (https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/blob/master/gr-digital/python/digital/gmsk.py) is pretty much identical and could probably be consolidated. Main difference is the default sensitivity parameter